# Why jqplot is not working with passing date

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, date, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I have used line chart of jqPlot which is working fine till the below code.

**Working Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var line1=[['1',3],['2',5], ['3',10]]

          var plot1 = $.jqplot ('mychart', [line1],
                  {
                title:'Default Date Axis',
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
                }
            },
            series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
          }
      );             
    });
```

**Output of Working Code Here**

[image]
Now, If I pass date in x-axis of line chart it does not show the line and x-axis as date.

**Not Working Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // var line1=[['1',3],['2',5], ['3',10]]
         var line1=[['2008-08-12',3],['2008-09-12',5], ['2008-10-12',10]]

          var plot1 = $.jqplot ('mychart', [line1],
                  {
                title:'Default Date Axis',
                axes:{
                    xaxis:{
                        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
                    }
                },
                series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
              }
          );             
        });
```

**Output of Not Working Code Here**
[image]

That is the problem that I am facing here. I also used this link
[jqplot date-axes](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/date-axes.html) but this also does not help me so far.
What should I do to solve this problem.
I need to show the date at x-axis.

Comment: Did you try to also specify time part (for example '2008-08-12 00:00AM')? (assuming you included required js file)

Comment: yes, I tried time part 'var line1=[['2008-08-12 00:00AM',3],['2008-09-12 00:00AM',5], ['2008-10-12 00:00AM',10]]' but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a reference to the axisDateRender Javascript file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy33ea54/13/) which uses your code sample above and renders the x-axis. If you notice the x-axis labels are very squashed together. You can use the `tickInterval` property of `xaxis` to change the tick interval:

```
xaxis:{
    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
    tickInterval:'2 weeks'
}
```

See the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dy33ea54/14/)